# Flutter - How to put two Columns inside a Row, one Column expanded, the other fit its content text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there a way to achieve this layout with flutter? With one Column expanded, and the other Column shrink to fit the texts inside, within a Row.

I'm from a web background, I know I can do it with Flex-grow and Flex-shring along with whitespace:nowrap.

**I would like to achieve this layout**

[image: I would like to achieve this layout]

But in flutter I tried:

1. This will give me two equal width columns:

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Text('Monthly Membership'), Text('Subscription')],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                '+100',
                maxLines: 1,
                softWrap: false,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              ),
              Text(
                '18 Sept 2021',
                maxLines: 1,
                softWrap: false,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

2. This will give an error.

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3024f relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Text('Monthly Membership'), Text('Subscription')],
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              '+100',
              maxLines: 1,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
            Text(
              '18 Sept 2021',
              maxLines: 1,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Are you using this row inside `Column`?

Comment: Yes the row is also inside a larger column of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second attempt fails because `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` takes all of the horizontal space available, but a `Row` gives its children an unbounded width constraint.  This forces the column to have infinite width, which is impossible.  There are two options to fix this:

1. Use a different `crossAxisAlignment`

This will make each child of the `Column` take as much space as it's going to take.  Based on your image, you probably want `CrossAxisAlignment.center`, which will center the column's children.  The column will take its width from the larger of the two Text widgets.

```dart
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          // ...
```

2. Use [`IntrinsicWidth`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html)

`IntrinsicWidth` will measure the width that the Column wants to be, then give it that width.  This will give the `Column` a tight width constraint in a second layout pass, which will make `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` work as intended.

```dart
        IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            // ...
```

Both options will layout the second column with unbounded width, which means that if you have very long text, it might make the first column very small.  If you want to bound the width of the column, you can add a `ConstrainedBox` to either solution.

Comment: For this simple UI `Intrinsic` widget is not suited to use, Intrinsic is relatively expensive because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree. I and @Yeasin already mentioned how to solve more conveniently

Comment: I see this works fine with `Intrinsic`, @JahidulIslam do you mean there's a perfomance issue with this option?

Comment: @edward exactly, there's a performance issues

Answer (score 4):

Your code-snippet just works fine, just missing alignment.
About your desire UI, you just need to set alignment.

```dart
 Card(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: const [
                        Text('Monthly Membership'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Subscription'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          '+100',
                          maxLines: 1,
                          softWrap: false,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          '18 Sept 2021',
                          maxLines: 1,
                          softWrap: false,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, If you add more text to "Monthly Membership" area, it will not go pass the 50% mark. I would like to have the left text expand all the wait til the right section

Comment: In that case, you can remove `Flexible` from second `Column`

Comment: without the second `Flexible`, it would be my attempt #2 which give an error of `NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`

Comment: Can you include parent's info, I'm not getting any error like you mentioned

Comment: it's in a tab of the home screen so the full path would be: `Scaffold` -> `IndexedStack` -> `Scaffold` -> `SingleChildScrollView` -> `Column` -> `Padding` -> `Container` -> (The Row and Two columns)

Comment: try with Providing  fixed height before column,